# Get default value of a node field

Tags: database

I have a field on a node which has a default value set, I need to access the default value of that field. But, I don't want to load any nodes of that type and access the field definitions, nor do I want to manually write a `db_query` and fetch the value directly from the db, I know there is a proper way to do it I just don't know of it.

Drupal 8.6.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [FieldDefinitionInterface::getDefaultValueLiteral](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldDefinitionInterface.php/function/FieldDefinitionInterface%3A%3AgetDefaultValueLiteral/8.6.x):

```
$definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'page');
if (isset($definitions['field_example'])) {
  $default_value = $definitions['field_example']->getDefaultValueLiteral();
}
```